# Codename one side Navigation panel

Tags: codenameone

I have created the side navigation using

```
form.addCommand("Logo");
```

Is that possible to remove default padding given to the side Navigation panel. I have changed the side navigation color using the theme.res file(side navigation panel).

Comment: That code won't compile so you didn't use that. The side navigation panel customizes the open panel. Provide a screenshot to illustrate what you need but first I suggest checking this out: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-create-gorgeous-sidemenu.html